# How to know from where the RTMP stream is starting and where it is ending using wireshark

Tags: wireshark, rtmp

I need to build a RTMP parser . For that I need to know from where the RTMP packet starts and where it ends in a bytestream. I analysed the RTMP stream using wireshark.What I observed is that RTMP packet is packaged(encapsulated) inside TCP packet which is in turn packaged(encapsulated) inside IPV4 packet. This was the behavior for all the RTMP packets except Video data RTMP packets and Aggregate RTMP packets.To build a parser I need to know from where the RTMP packet is starting and where it is ending.But with Video data RTMP packet and Aggregate RTMP packets its not getting possible because these packets are not packaged inside IPV4 packet.The data for RTMP packet is shown in a different window in wireshark(named Unchunked RTMP).Can anyone help me know how wireshark is getting to know where the TCP packet is ending and where the RTMP Video packet and RTMP Aggregate packet is starting ??? What is the logic of Wireshark for this or what I can do to achieve the same ???

Comment: RTMP works over TCP as far as I know. If you say some RTMP packets are not packaged inside IP packets at all, then logically how are they being transmitted to your IP address?

Comment: @Æðelstan I completely agree with you but that' the thing i am unable to figure out.What ideally should happen is that RTMP is packaged inside TCP which is in turn packaged inside IPv4.Hence the size of RTMP packet must be included in the TOTAL LENGTH FIELD of IPv4 packet.This means the size of RTMP packet must contribute to the size of IPv4 packet but unfortunately this is not happening in case of some Video Data RTMP packets and Aggregate RTMP packets.What you think can be the reason ??

Comment: I would like to see the packet capture if you could just post a link to it please. Off the bat, I would think it's a bug, have you tried another capture on the same stream?